# Windows sees iPhone but iTunes does not

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, unix, virtualbox

I'm running Windows 7 in VirtualBox with Linux as a host. I'd like to sync my iPhone with iTunes installed in the VM.

I've set up USB filters in VirtualBox, and Windows sees my iPhone upon connecting, however its icon doesn't show up in iTunes.

It did show up *once* after a few trials, I don't know if it was random or if I did something, but I can't get it to appear again.

This is what Windows displays when I connect my iPhone:

[image]

How do I get iTunes to detect my iPhone?

I've tried restarting my computer, the VM, and the iPhone, with no progress. Also, when I click "Open device to view files", I see only the DCIM folder in "Internal storage".

- iTunes version is 12.3.1 which is latest

Answer (score -1):

Try updating to your iTunes into the latest version. It happened to me one time but when I upgraded the my iTunes to the latest version, then it worked fine.

Comment: iTunes version is 12.3.1 which is the latest one.